# Cannot start minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing, minikube

I can't start minikube. Everything seems to be ok, but [image]

When I open VirtualBox, and then click on 'minikube', it shows this...
[image]

I see the first picture, and minikube is not configured even after 5 minutes. So, how can I get minikube configured?

Comment: Try to run `minikube --logtostderr -v 1 start` and see if you get any more logs out of it

Comment: To clarify: are you experiencing that `minikube status` does nothing? I would not expect to see interesting text on the console of that VM. If you want to obtain a shell in the vm, `minikube ssh` should do that, or you can use `minikube ssh-key` and the ssh client of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Error could be based on the environment settings too. So please provide additional information about it.
Nevertheless, check the minikube logs for more information.

`minikube start --logtostderr --show-libmachine-logs`

Hope this helps you figure out the issue.

I faced a similar situation with minikube. But then realized that my network blocked certain images from being pulled. My error looked something like this.
`unable to pull sandbox image "gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0"`
So in this case, I used a VPN connection and it resolved my issue.